# Cannot Read Property of undefined Object in dependencies array in useEffect or useCallback in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, usecallback

I have a `useCallback()` method below to improve the performance. This will be same logic with `useEffect()`

If I have a dependency which is `router.asPath`, but sometimes the `router` is null, which may cause the function crash.

In order to improvement performance, I do not want to put the whole object of `router`, as other fields changes, I do not want rerun the function.

Any suggest?

```
  const recordProduct = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch(setNextCollectionScroll(router.asPath, hit.handle))
  }, [dispatch, hit.handle, router])
```

The ideal dependency: `[dispatch, hit.handle, router.asPath]`
But I have to do it now: due to the `router` object may be null: `[dispatch, hit.handle, router]`

Comment: Maybe you should check if `router.asPath` is not undefined before calling `dispatch()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what router are you using, and if you should look elsewhere, but in your simple case of checking dependencies in both `useEffect` and `useCallback` you can use [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) from JS.

```js
const recordProduct = useCallback(() => {
  dispatch(setNextCollectionScroll(router.asPath, hit.handle))
}, [dispatch, hit.handle, router?.asPath])
```

When `router` is null, `?` will skip trying to get `asPath` and you will not get a runtime error.

**SIDENOTE**
In my opinion you should always use a specific property in an object that you are depending on, especially if you are using a third-party library, as it may happen that they return same object reference with a different value (this should be labeled as badly written library, but just in case depend on properties).

It is easier to follow the flow of data and why a particular dependency hook fires.

Comment: This did work. Actually router will not be null in prod, but only has issue in unit tests, where router is null, but I do not want mock as router null should also pass the test. This should keep code clean as well as keep the performance.